# How to access alternate array elements in twig using index?

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to access alternate elements in an array using its index. 
Something like this :

```
for(i=0;i<count(myarray);i++)
{
print myarray[i+1];
}
```

How can I do this with twig ?

Answer (score 3):

```
{% set arrayLength = myarray|length - 1 %}

{% for i in range(0, arrayLength, 2) %}
    {{ myarray[i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

This should print this elements: `myarray[0]`, `myarray[2]`, `myarray[4]`, and so on ...

#### Explaination

1. Set a variable arrayLength to keep number of array's element. We need to set it one unit behind the "real" count as array is zero-indexed
2. Loop in range from 0 to arrayLength (count - 1 as explained above) with a 2 step (third argument stands for "increase index of n each step"; in this case "n" is 2)
3. Print the result

Of course you could also skip `arrayLength` setter and use directly

```
{% for i in range(0, myarray|length - 1, 2) %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer from far the [DonCallisto Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34895109/2454790), but for diversity of answers here is one other...

**Context** :

```
myarray:
    - a
    - b
    - c
    - d
    - e
    - f
    - g
    - h
```

**Twig** :

```
{% for key, value in myarray if not key % 2 %}
    {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Results** :

```
a
c
e
g
```

**TwigFiddle** : http://twigfiddle.com/hmzuye

Comment: This is also a good one and I love when users try to give an alternative to OP.